# python: how to make programm press some buttons after if else

Tags: python, button, speechsynthesizer

I have a programm which makes something when I talk in microphone. So I don't know how to make it press buttons by itself. I made a simple if else request where I say some words and it must press buttons.
If you can say how to loop it, so it won't close after a first answer to request, then you can try to help with that

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.